# W-2 from company despite no longer a current employee

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, form-w-2

I last worked for this company in August of 2019. I am trying to file my taxes for 2020. I received a W-2 for 2020 because I received a direct deposit from this company in March of 2020. I believe this happened because I was an hourly employee whose timesheet needed to be approved by their manager. I believe some of my hours sat in limbo for seven months. I don't have any inside contacts at this company and they have 100,000 employees (very bureaucratic). This employer is in another state (CA) so I would prefer not to file another state tax return. How should I proceed?

Comment: Please add a state tag.  Is there a threshold in that state for filing a tax return, as is the amount under that?  If not, the only answer we can give you is to follow the law.

Comment: Just to be clear: Your old employer gave you one last pay deposit in 2020, and you just got a W-2 for it. The issue you have is that they withheld CA income tax, and you don’t want to file a CA tax return. Does that accurately describe your situation?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score -1):

A giant company will have a dedicated payroll department that can likely fix the 2020 error, if it is an error. But they won't make the income disappear; they'll just move the income to 2019. You then might have to file amended 2019 returns.